# Oracle "NOT IN" not returning correct result?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, subquery

I'm comparing two tables that share unique values between each other using `NOT IN`  function in `Oracle` but I'm getting

```
select count(distinct CHARGING_ID)   from BILLINGDB201908 where CDR_TYPE='GPRSO'
```

the output is: `521254` for all charging ids --< this is the total unique charging ID's in BILLINGDB201908

Now I want to find id's in table BILLINGDB201908  that also exist in table CBS_CHRG_ID_AUG

```
select count(distinct CHARGING_ID)   from BILLINGDB201908 where CDR_TYPE='GPRSO'
AND charging_id IN (select CHARGINGID from CBS_CHRG_ID_AUG);
```

--- the result back`315567` charging ID exist BILLINGDB201908 and also exist in CBS_CHRG_ID_AUG

Now I want to find charging ids that not exist in  CBS_CHRG_ID_AUG but exist BILLINGDB201908

```
select count(distinct CHARGING_ID)   from prmdb.CDR_TAPIN_201908@prmdb where CDR_TYPE='GPRSO'
AND charging_id NOT IN (select CHARGINGID from CBS_CHRG_ID_AUG);
```

--the result back `0` !? I should get `205687` exactly because `521254-315567` = 205687 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing record is having null value CHARGINGID.

Please try doing select where CHARGINGID is null vs is not null

Comment: Thanks there was only 1 `NULL` row with `NULL` value in `CBS_CHRG_ID_AUG` once delete the query work fine and return the correct tresult.

Answer (score 4):

`NOT IN` returns *no rows* if any value from the subquery is `NULL`.  Hence, I strongly, strongly recommend `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT count(distinct CHARGING_ID)   
FROM prmdb.CDR_TAPIN_201908@prmdb  ct
WHERE CDR_TYPE = 'GPRSO' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM CBS_CHRG_ID_AUG ccia
                  WHERE ccia.charging_id = ct.charging_id
                 );
```

I also recommend changing your first query to `EXISTS`.  In fact, just don't use `IN` and `NOT IN` with subqueries, and you won't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks Gordon your query work fine too but I don't understand this part in the sub query ?  `SELECT 1`.

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna . . . `EXISTS` simply checks for the existence of a row.  The `1` provides a column for the row to avoid a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `not exists` rather than `not in`; it is `null`-safe, and usually more efficient:

```
select count(distinct charging_id)   
from billingdb201908 b
where 
    b.cdr_type = 'gprso'
    and not exists (select 1 from cbs_chrg_id_aug a where a.chargingid = b.chargingid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this list using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

SQL to return list of charging ids that not exist in CBS_CHRG_ID_AUG but exist BILLINGDB201908 -

```
select count(distinct CHARGING_ID)   
from prmdb.CDR_TAPIN_201908@prmdb a 
left join CBS_CHRG_ID_AUG b on a.CHARGING_ID = b.CHARGINGID 
where a.CDR_TYPE='GPRSO' and b.CHARGINGID is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two dangers with `not in` when the subquery key may contain nulls:

1. If there actually is a null value, you may not get the result you were expecting (as you have found). The database is actually correct, even though nobody in the history of SQL has ever expected this result.
2. Even if all key values are populated, if it is possible for the key column to be null (if it is not defined as `not null`) then the database has to check in case there is a null value, so queries are limited to inefficient row by row filter operations, which can perform disastrously for large volumes. (This was true historically, although these days there is a [Null-aware anti-join](http://structureddata.org/2008/05/22/null-aware-anti-join/) and so the performance issue may not be so disastrous.)

```sql
create table demo (id) as select 1 from dual;

select * from demo;

        ID
----------
         1
```

```sql
create table table_with_nulls (id) as (
  select 2 from dual union all
  select null from dual
);

select * from table_with_nulls;

        ID
----------
         2
```

```sql
select d.id
from   demo d
where  d.id not in
       ( select id from table_with_nulls );

no rows selected
```

```sql
select d.id
from   demo d
where  d.id not in
       ( select id from table_with_nulls
         where  id is not null );

        ID
----------
         1
```

The reason is that `1 <> null` is `null`, not `false`. If you substitute a fixed list for the `not in` subquery, it would be:

```
select d.id
from   demo d
where  d.id not in (2, null);
```

which is really the same thing as

```
select d.id
from   demo d
where  d.id <> 2 and d.id <> null;
```

Obviously `d.id <> null` will never be true. This is why your `not in` query returned no rows.